# Java: Tokenizer get token after next token

Tags: java, string, token, stringtokenizer

Is there a better way to get the `token` after `next token`?

This is how I do it now:

```
StringTokenizer inputTokens2 = new StringTokenizer(input);
while (inputTokens2.hasMoreTokens()){
    StringTokenizer nextToken = new Stringtokenizer(inputTokens2.nextToken());
}
```

What I want to achieve is get the number user enters separated by spaces " ", and decide if its valid phone number. But if the number contains for example "...20 5..." then I have to check both versions of numbers "...25...." or "...205....". Thats why I want to use the `Token` after next one. If next `Token` ends in "0" and the `token` after that is single digit then there are 2 versions.

Comment: Just call `nextToken()` twice? Better yet, don't use `StringTokenizer` at all.

Comment: @shmosel `nextToken()` returns `string` not `StringTokenizer` so I cant use it twice

Comment: Why do you want to tokenise the result of `nextToken`?  Calling `nextToken` simply moves the `StringTokenizer` to the next available token, so call as many times as you need to get the effect you want

Comment: @aggtr I'm not sure what you mean. Why would you want it to return `StringTokenizer`?

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is not recommended for use in new code. It's only around for backwards compatibility reasons. I second what @shmosel said, it's better not to use it at all, but creating a new one off of a token returned from one doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @DavidConrad please check edited post

Comment: For that I would just use `String[] tokens = input.split(" ");`

Comment: What's your **exact** problem? Perhaps there are better ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer use is discouraged. Java has "the string".split("\s"), which is recommended.

```
 String[] result = input.split("\\s");
 for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
     System.out.println(result[x]);
```

You can check this on the official documentation by oracle website.

Answer (score 0):

To find out values separated by spaces, StringTokenizer is very runtime efficient as compared to `.split( regex )`.

Primarily StringTokenizer provides Strings of space separated values and can be used as follows:

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);
 while( st.hasMoreTokens() ) System.out.println( st.nextToken() );
```

Although Java8 documentation suggests to use `.split()` over Tokenizer, more can be known here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html